# Inserting a background color behind a text changed with psfrag

Tags: backgrounds, eps, psfrag

I have just started to play with psfrag to change some tags into eps images.
I am looking for a simple way to add a background color to a text inserted using psfrag.
For example in:

```
\begin{figure}
\psfrag{text}{$X$}
\includegraphics{figure.eps}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to have "X", which has replaced "text" in figure.eps, to lay at the center of a white rectangle with no borders, just as a background color, so that I could cover what is behind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\psfrag{text}{\colorbox{blue}{$X$}}`

Comment: solved @DavidCarlisle, many thanks. If I can bother you with another question, there is the possibility of moving vertically or horizontally the text inserted with psfrag in addiction to the optional positioning arguments of the package?

Comment: you can use raisebox, or hspace o use a picture environment and \put text at arbitrary coordinate from its natural position

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it seems to work in this version:
`\psfrag{v}{\hspace{-0.25cm}\colorbox{white}{$V$}}`. What do you thins about my solution?
Can you please give me an example of inserting a txt in an eps figure using \put? I did not understand much this command, many thanks.

Comment: `\psfrag{v}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(1cm,-2cm){colorbox{white}{$V$}}\end{picture}}` would offset it horizontally and vertically,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\psfrag{text}{\colorbox{blue}{$X$}}
```

or to shift horizontally

```
\psfrag{v}{\hspace{-0.25cm}\colorbox{white}{$V$}}
```

Or in both directions

```
\psfrag{v}{\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(1cm,-2cm){\colorbox{white}{$V$}}\end{picture}}
```

Comment: @umby fixed, thanks

Comment: thank you so much!